# JSR303 ConstraintValidator, how to show the message without an error page

Tags: jsf-2, java-ee-6, bean-validation

Im working with JSF 2.0 and Glassfish v3. I was testing the functionality of JSR303 bean validation, so I created a validator which implements [`ConstraintValidator`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/validation/ConstraintValidator.html) and then annotate that on a property wich I want to validate.

It works fine, but it displays a Glassfish default error page. I don't want this to be displayed, I would rather have the message displayed in a `<h:outputText>` or something.

Does anybody know how to achieve this?

Here is my validator method:

```
@Override
public boolean isValid(String searchArg, ConstraintValidatorContext ctx) {

    boolean searchArgCorrect = true;
    FacesMessage msg;
    if(searchArg!=null) {
        ctx.disableDefaultConstraintViolation();
        if(searchArg.length() < 3) {
            ctx.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate("Searcharg is too short").addConstraintViolation();
            searchArgCorrect=false;

            msg = new FacesMessage(
                    FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,
                    "Searcharg is too short", null);

            throw new  ValidatorException(msg);
        }
    }

    return searchArgCorrect;
}
```

PS: I know that there are easier ways to validate the length of a string, but the above code snippet is only for demo/testing purposes. I have another plans with the validator.

Comment: @BalusC: I did a second answer... because here in the comment field there's not enough space..

Answer (score 6):

You're mixing two concepts: JSF validation and JSR 303 bean validation. You're implementing JSR303 bean validation, but you're throwing a JSF-specific `ValidatorException`.

The method should not throw an exception. The method should just return `true` or `false` depending on the validation outcome. The message has to be definied in `ValidationMessages.properties`. JSF will then display it in a `<h:message>` which is associated with the input component.

See also [this documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.0.1/reference/en/html/validator-customconstraints.html) on creating custom constraints with a message.

---

Or if you're *actually* after a standard JSF validator, then you should be implementing [`javax.faces.validator.Validator`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/validator/Validator.html) instead, annotate it with [`@FacesValidator`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/validator/FacesValidator.html) and declare it in view by `<f:validator>`. It can throw a `ValidatorException` and the message will be displayed in `<h:message>` associated with the input component.